# Will Oracle Data Pump affect performance?

Tags: performance, oracle, datapump

Would like to know what would happen if I run data pump on a production server which is being used live. Will this affect DB performance for Update/Insert activities ??

Thank You.

Comment: Closing this as "not a real question" seems perverse when there are three answers to it.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Will reopen if there are some more details in OP ;-)

Comment: I think it's pretty clear really -- is there a performance impact on update/insert if data pump is being run on a database at the same time.

Comment: I had this same question because it's not clearly outlined in the documentation I'm using.  That is, this question & answers is valuable to me.  It's a pretty high hit on google for "is data pump safe for production"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, any activity on any server running any software will always have the potential to affect other users.  Whether and how badly it actually will affect other activities depends on a variety of factors.  If the day-to-day activity is bottlenecked on I/O, for example, then adding a DataPump export that generates a large amount of additional I/O will significantly slow day-to-day operations.  If the server is mostly idle during the day, on the other hand, running a DataPump export at the same time probably won't substantially affect performance.

Assuming that you are exporting a reasonably large amount of data, it would certainly be conventional to wait until at least off-peak hours to run the export rather than doing it during the middle of the day.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from Justin's answer, a data pump export is going to run in serializable read consistency mode, so will require that UNDO information is preserved for the duration of the export. This may mean you need a larger undo area than is normally the case for your system if the export takes a long time.